# Echo a for in a text file .bat file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, echo

When I run my bat file it closes. I have determined that the issue is in this line because echo is trying to print the %%a value and it is empty. All I want is to have in arranque.bat `for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (information.txt) do set coin=%%a`.

The line where I'm getting the error:

```
echo for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (information.txt) do set coin=%%a >> arranque.bat
```

Comment: Double every percent symbol if you want to output that entire literal string to the output file.

Comment: With %%%a the output return %%a (like i want) but it doesnt returns the next part (in (information.txt) do set coin=%%a)

Comment: you seem to be confused on how these commands work. Anything after the word ECHO redirected to STDOUT. It will not execute the FOR command. You seem to want the FOR command to execute but also want to output it as a literal string to another file.

Comment: I dont want to execute the for command, just output in another file the text "for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (information.txt) do set coin=%%a" nothing more, plane text. The for command will be executed in arranque.bat later.

Comment: Please read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Completely agree. Sorry for the mistake, Ill do my best for improve my nexts questions. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, if I understand correctly, what you're looking for is:

```bat
Echo For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=6" %%%%A In ("information.txt") Do Set "coin=%%%%A">>"arranque.bat"
```

Comment: The .bat file stills closing itself. Ill add all the code in less thna an hour and see if i didnt figures out well the issue. Thanks for the the asnwer anyways.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with my provided code, so I guarantee that you've failed to provide the rest of the code and that it is part of  a parenthesised block. If my assumption is correct you'll need to escape the closing parenthesis on your `For` command using a caret: `Echo For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=6" %%%%A In ("information.txt"^) Do Set "coin=%%%%A">>"arranque.bat"`

Comment: Adn you were well. I am sorry, I make the mistake of dont share all the code because i thought I had the issue. Ill do my best for improve my next questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to set variable coin **and** append to file

```
for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (information.txt) do (
    set "coin=%%a"
    >> arranque.bat echo=%%a
)
```

If there is more than one line in information.txt, each line will replace coin content, so after the for only the last one will persist.

Comment: I want to have in arranque.bat the same lane that i want to echo. In arranque.bat: "for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (information.txt) do set coin=%%a". With ur sugestion im getting "%a". Sorry if i didnt explained what I want.

Comment: Sorry I didn't take care case is important on for meta variables `%%A` -> `%%a`